# Use a function with multiple results as arguments

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I have a function which returns multiple values, can I use that function somehow directly in another function's argument list? When I try it (naively) I get:

```
def one() :
    return 3, 2
def two(a, b):
    return a + b
two(one())
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-86-27980b86a2c0> in <module>()
  3 def two(a, b):
  4     return a + b
----> 5 two(one())

TypeError: two() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
```

Of course I can do something like

```
def one() :
    return 3, 2
def two(a, b):
    return a + b
a, b = one()
two(a, b)
```

Comment: As an explanation of *why* it is only one parameter, `one()` returns a single tuple - `return` really only returns one object, although of course that can be a tuple of other objects.

Comment: As a matter of fact it's a duplicate of a duplicate. Sometimes its a bit hard to formulate my questions the right way especially when learning a new Programming langage for me. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure.

```
two(*one())
```

`*` is argument unpacking

Useful reading: [Understanding the asterisk(*) of Python](https://medium.com/understand-the-python/understanding-the-asterisk-of-python-8b9daaa4a558)